# Laravel Query get row based on 2 dependent column

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Help me to query this.
I have a Laravel app where have a table that has 3 columns (quartal, year, value).

| quartal | year | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 | 3 |
| 2 | 2019 | 5 |
| 3 | 2019 | 5 |
| 4 | 2019 | 10 |
| 1 | 2020 | 7 |
| 2 | 2020 | 5 |

For example, I want to get the value from quartal 3 years 2019 to quartal 2 years 2020
how to make the query for this case?
for the year I can use between but for the quartal, It depends on the year.

here is my current query. but it does not work really well

```
DB::table($table)
->whereBetween('year',[$startYear, $endYear])
->whereBetween('quartal',[$startQuartal, $endQuartal])
->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is you need to create a compound column from `quartal` and `year` and then query that.

```
DB::table($table)
->whereRaw("concat(year,quartal) >= ?", "$startYear$startQuartal")
->whereRaw("concat(year,quartal) <= ?", "$endYear$endQuartal")
->get();
```

You can refer this for the SQL query https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4GRH5RKqQi2Fc6wVvxK8C2/0

Comment: this is working great for me. but still, edit it a bit '"concat(year,quartal)>=$startYear$startQuartal"', don't know why sometimes it giving data less than what it should if it has a "?". Thankyou for the solution

Comment: That's not a good idea, you will be vulnerable to SQL injection attach. I would recommend debugging using `toSsql()` and `getBindings()` to see what's really happening with the query.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with filter function also and it an easy way just like

```
$startYear = 2019
$endyear = 2020
$startQuartar = 3
$endQuartar = 2
DB::table($table)
->whereBetween('year',[$startYear, $endYear])
->get()->filter(function($query) use 
($startYear,$endYear,$startQuartar,$endQuartar){
    if($query->year == $startYear and $query->quartar < $startQuartar){
       return false;
    }
    if($query->year == $endYear and $query->quartar > $endQuartar){
      return false;
    }
      return true;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

How about adding the quartal to the year?

```php
DB::table($table)
    ->whereBetween(
        DB::raw('year + (quartal - 1) / 4'),
        [
            $startYear + ($startQuartal - 1) / 4,
            $endYear + ($endQuartal - 1) / 4
        ]
    )
    ->get();
```